# How do I parse a date field and generate a date in string format in NiFi

Tags: apache-nifi

Each of my flow file contains 2000 records. I would like to parse 01/01/2000 into a column year = 2000, column month = Jan and column day = 01

i.e. the input column 01/01/2000 into 3 values separated by commas 01,Jan,2000

Comment: Are you using NiFi's record processors with a schema for your data?

Comment: @Bryan, yes. I am looking at CSV or Json reader/writer

Comment: Ok will write an answer in a few minutes

Comment: Fantastic! I thought this couldn't be possible at all

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lets say you have a schema like this for a person with a birthday and you want to split out the birthday:

```
{
  "name": "person",
  "namespace": "nifi",
  "type": "record",
  "fields": [
    { "name": "first_name", "type": "string" },
    { "name": "last_name", "type": "string" },
    { "name": "birthday", "type": "string" }
  ]
}
```

You would need to modify the schema so it had the fields you want to add:

```
{
  "name": "person",
  "namespace": "nifi",
  "type": "record",
  "fields": [
    { "name": "first_name", "type": "string" },
    { "name": "last_name", "type": "string" },
    { "name": "birthday", "type": "string" },
    { "name": "birthday_year", "type": ["null", "string"] },
    { "name": "birthday_month", "type": ["null", "string"] },
    { "name": "birthday_day", "type": ["null", "string"] }
  ]
}
```

Lets say the input record has the following text:

```
bryan,bende,1980-01-01
```

We can use UpdateRecord with a CsvReader and CsvWriter, and UpdateRecord can populate the three fields we want by parsing the original birthday field.

[image]

If we send the output to LogAttribute we should see the following now:

```
first_name,last_name,birthday,birthday_year,birthday_month,birthday_day
bryan,bende,1980-01-01,1980,01,01
```

Here is the link to the record path guide for details on the toDate and format functions:

https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/record-path-guide.html

Answer (score 3):

You can use UpdateRecord for this, assuming your input record has the date column called "myDate", you'd set the `Replacement Value Strategy` to `Record Path Value`, and your user-defined properties might look something like:

`/day   format(/myDate, "dd")
/month  format(/myDate, "MMM")
/year   format(/myDate, "YYYY")`

Your output schema would look like this:

```
{
 "namespace": "nifi",
 "name": "myRecord",
 "type": "record",
 "fields": [
  {"name": "day","type": "int"},
  {"name": "month","type": "string"},
  {"name": "year","type": "int"}
 ]
}
```

Comment: Ha I hadn't loaded the page to see Bryan's answer, his is more helpful and complete :)