# Epoch date converion fails with apache-nifi

Tags: date, datetime, oracle10g, apache-nifi, epoch

I have QueryDatabaseTableRecord to get data from Oracle table.

In my oracle table, I have following data

```
id,name,bday
1,sachith,17-SEP-1990
2,nalaka,16-MAR-2020
```

When I run and get data, its changed into bigint.

```
1,sachith,653523824000
2,nalaka,1584311083000
```

In Record Writer : CSV
                 : Date format : yyyy-mm-dd

But yet its not working. Do I have to use intermediate UpdateRecord processor and update date fields as [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51675050/how-do-i-parse-a-date-field-and-generate-a-date-in-string-format-in-nifi)?

Edit :

After doing some research, I could add `UpdateRecord` processor with

```
/my_date_colum : ${filed.value:format("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS")}
```

But this fails with negative epoch values.

> Error : Could not implicitly convert input to Date -104697000000

How can I handle this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This statement should work:
`${field.value:toDate():format('yyyy-MMM-dd')}`